# Is definition of Monad causing an uncallable function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads, newtype

I am playing with Monads in Haskell trying to get good at it.
This piece of coded I tried to finish by writing the right sides of the definitions in the instantiation of the Trace Monad.

The function and the newtype I didn't provide, they were there as part of the exercise.

As you can see I get an error. I am not sure I understand the error.

I interpret the error as: The function show isn't declared for the type (Trace Integer) and it therefore can't use print on the provided input 2.

If this is a correct interpretation where did I then make the mistake, in the function call, or in the definition of the monad? And how to correct it?

```
newtype Trace a = T (a, String) --My comment: here we apparently don't have a constructor ?


instance Monad Trace where 
  (T p) >>= f = f (fst p)
  return x = T(x, mempty)

traceable :: String -> (t -> a) -> t -> Trace a
traceable name f = \x -> T(f x, name ++" called.")

OUTPUT:

ghci> traceable "customStr" (*2) 2

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    * No instance for (Show (Trace Integer))
        arising from a use of `print'
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the monad definition, you just didn't define a `Show` instance for `Trace` so it doesn't know how to print (`show`) the value

Comment: Btw `Trace` *does* have a constructor: it's called `T`

Comment: How do I correct define show for Trace. then? Shall I have to include it on the left side `return show x = T(x, mempty)` doesn't seem to provide  results.

Comment: `newtype Trace a = T (a, String) deriving Show`.

Comment: ahh, thank you guys. I see. But the monad doesn't seem to make much difference in this case. If I comment out the return and the bind statement non-simultanously I can still call the function below. But the exercise was supposed to show how the monad works based on the function. How can I executue the monad?

Comment: Think of `traceable` as a way to convert any regular function `t -> a` into a monadic one `t -> Trace a`. That does not need the monadic stuff at all. To bring the monad definition into play you need to use `>>=`/`return` somehow e.g. using a `do` block as in `do x <- traceable "succ" succ 4 ; return (1000+x)`

Comment: Also note that the Monad instance is broken. It doesn't obey the law "for all (m :: Trace a), m >>= return === m". Specifically, `T (1, "hi") >>= return  === T (1, "")`

Comment: @chi , thank you. Is there another way to bring the monad into play than using the do notation, I wonder? In LYAH: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe they do so without the syntatic sugar of 'do' for the Maybe-monad.

Comment: @Carl so are you suggesting, that I rewrite the 'return'-part.  What would that look like, considering that it doesn't take more arguments than `x` , and that the exercise precribes that I am to define the right side only?

Comment: What led to that conclusion? The statement of the law contains both `>>=` and `return`. It's a description of their behavior when combined. Just in general, it's far more likely that you need to be careful with `>>=` because, as you note, `return` is usually a lot more constrained. In this case it is `>>=` that needs work. As a hint, consider that it's just throwing information away at one point. That's something it can't do if it's going to obey the law I mentioned.

Comment: @Carl , I see that it is throwing away information. But the function `f` is bound by the `>>=` to obey: `(a -> Trace b)` so you can't pass another argument, that is the second part of the tuple - the string.  I take that what you are hinting at is the second monad law; That is, Right identity. I tried to extract the first of whatever `f` returns, like so: `T(fst (f (fst p)), snd p)`  but this still doens't work. I get: `Couldn't match expected type: (b, b1) with actual type: Trace b`. Could you give some more hint?

Comment: @Carl, I think I figured it out: I wrote something like: `(T p) >>= f = let T(newa, str) = f (fst p) in T(newa, (snd p))`

Comment: In general how can I use return to bring the monad  into play without using the syntatic sugar of do: I try this `return (4, "custom") :: Trace (Int, String)` which works. This doesn't work `return 4  :: Trace (Int, String)` however and I get: `No instance for (Num (Int, String)) arising from the literal `4'`

Comment: @Piskator You're on the right track with that change - but now you're throwing away part of the result of calling `f`. You should also be using `str`.

Comment: @Carl thanks for the response. But I would argue that what I do above is the right thing, and when I use the do expression suggested above  `do x <- traceable "succ" succ 4 ; return (1000+x)` it does give the right output: `T (1005,"succ called.")`. So I don't think it need to change further. If you can show me otherwise though, I am open for suggestions.

Do you know however how I can call `return  4  :: Trace (Int, String)`?